# Will linking to very old versions of glibc introduce security vulnerabilities?

Tags: security, glibc, dynamic-linking

I am compiling a program (which happens to be written in Rust) that I would like to be compatible with very old and out-of-date systems, including some EOL-ed linux distributions. The main barrier to doing this is that the older systems do not have recent glibc binaries.

The solution is not so complicated, you must simply link to a very old binary. However, these old binaries are known to have many security vulnerabilities, some quite severe. I would like to maintain compatibility with people running these ancient and insecure glibc installations without putting my more responsible users at risk.

Will linking to ancient glibc versions introduce vulnerabilities on systems whose installations are up to date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will linking to ancient glibc versions introduce vulnerabilities on systems whose installations are up to date?

Not if you link dynamically.

Any fixes that affect GLIBC reside in `libc.so.6` (and associated libraries). These libraries normally come from the system, so on an up-to-date system they are up-to-date (by definition), and your program will automatically use them and will therefore be up-to-date itself.

In fact, this is one of the major reasons for dynamic linking: an updated `libc.so.6` fixes *all* (dynamically linked) programs on the system at once. With static linking, *every* program would have to be re-linked for the fix to take effect.